# Multiple prices option for item in Amazon In-App Purchase API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, amazon-appstore

I'm using amazon in app purchase library. I've run sample codes successfully. This sample code is for one item against one single price.

Now I want one item against more than one prices.

For example when I'll click on buy button the popup should show 2 or 3 prices and I'll select one price from them. Or can I input my own price to purchase the item like what we do in donate button with paypal library.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to assign multiple prices to one item in Amazon IAP.  To implement something similar though, you could setup multiple items to represent that one item at different prices.